# Is there a way to clear a file context after you've written data in it?

Tags: file, matlab, cmd

I have this program where I open a file and write data points in it but the problem is I have to do that inside a loop. it goes:

```
file1=importdata('myfile.txt','%s')

for k=1:1:128

fid=fopen('myfile2.txt','w+') % I write input to that file and pass it to my exe file

fprintf(fid,'input1')

fprintf(fid,'input2')

fprintf(fid,'input3')

 the 4th input (input4) is being taken from a diff file.txt and 

input4=sscanf(file1{k},'%s')

Val=str2double(input4)

fprintf(fid,'%.3f',Val)

fclose(fid)

[status,result]=system('command<myfile2.txt') 

M= sscanf(result,'%s')

more_result=[ Val M]

Fid2=fopen(myfile3.txt,'w+')

frpintf(Fid2,'%s', more_result)

end
```

This is a vague idea of the code.
Then I `sscanf` the results to get the a specific value (M) that I want.

I want to write Val and Z in another file but I only get the last value of each in the file because `fopen(fid,'w+')` keeps updating inside the loop. Using `a+` plus doesn't help and it keeps appending and never updates after the program is done running.

RIght now I am using a+ then I manually delete the content of that file after i'm done running..writing outside the loop gives me error. 
Is there a way I can clear the file after each run?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you open just once with `w+`, you can write multiple times. The first time will be the beginning of the file and after that data will be appended.

Put opening and closing outside the loop. Before the loop you put

```
fid=fopen('myfile2.txt','w+')
Fid2=fopen('myfile3.txt','w+')
```

And you can put closing after the loop

```
fclose(fid)
fclose(Fid2)
```

If this really really does not work, then I suggest opening the file once before the loop with `w'` which will empty the contents. Then you can use `a+` inside the loop to append data. You will have a clean file each time.

Comment: when i put it outside it only save the last points in the file which the point when the loop reach its limit

Comment: I've updated the answer, because of the better formatting options there